# Postman collection runner is very slow and newman run giving error

Tags: node.js, postman, newman

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TGkg.png)I have a collection with 5 folders, each folder having 1 or 2 requests.
It was working fine 2 days ago.
But now, when I am trying to run the folder with collection runner, the execution is extremely slow, it takes 15 mts to complete 30 iterations, Earlier it was taking 20 secs.

When I am running that collection through collection runner, it is again taking 15 mts, I am using csv file for the data.execution gets completed for 30 iterations but report is not generated.
It shows error at the end, Please find screenshot of the error.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Postman as well as node.js, still same issue.
I tried to increase memory using command "node  --max_old_space_size=2048 " . it throws error - Fatal process OOM in insufficient memory to create an Isolate

I also tried running newman command in other systems, throws same error.
Please help me find solution for this

node version-v10.16.2
npm version-6.13.1

Comment: have you updated the postman recently?

Comment: no, in fact reinstalled earlier version

Answer (score 0):

It was happening as the length of the response was quite large